# is it possible to get clipboard manager via intent-filter and broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, clipboardmanager

is it possible to get copied text via intent-filters and broadcast receiver?
I want to develop a dictionary application and when user copies text wherever in his phone I want to show the meaning of text.
currently I have tried using a Base Activity to register listener but i it does not meet my need.

```
 mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        listener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                performClipboardCheck();
            }
        };
        mClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

This how i did it,just open your app first then close it but you can also write service if want to run continues

for Java

```
final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    String a = clipboard.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Copy:\n"+a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

for kotlin

```
  clipboard= this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener (object : ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener{
            override fun onPrimaryClipChanged() {
              Log.d(TAG,"Copy:\n= "+clipboard.primaryClip.toString())
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a `service` to check clipboard and attach receiver to `ClipboardManager` there.
so the service class should be like:

```
class ClipBoardService : Service(), ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {
override fun onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    if (manager.primaryClip.itemCount > 0) {
        val clip = manager.primaryClip.getItemAt(0).text.toString()
        toast(clip)
    }
}


override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
    return Binder()
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    initReceiver()
    return START_STICKY
}

private fun initReceiver() {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    manager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(this)
    manager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(this)
}
}
```

and you can create a broadcast receiver with you own action and register it on your activity's `onStart` and unregister it on activity's `onStop` and then in your service using `sendBroadcast` method send intent to your activity

don't forget to declare service in your manifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".clipboard.ClipBoardService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to get copied text via intent-filters and broadcast receiver?

No.